# Can 2+ AngularJS modules be assigned to the same DOM element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario that is a classic portal/CMS widget scenario:

1. AngularJS may or may not be on the page
2. Any number of widgets may or may not be on the page
3. Each widget may be a member of a family of widgets and multiple families may be intertwined on the same page
4. More than one instance of a widget may be on the page
5. Different development teams will be assigned to different families of widgets

The "family" notion is simply that a group of widgets are related by data or purpose, communicating with each other and influencing each other's UI.  Also, multiple families could be intermingled on the same page.

AngularJS seems to push the developer toward one module at the root of the page using controllers for individual sections of the page.  However, this would mean that developers from different teams could be influencing the `pageApp` module in different conflicting ways.

It seems like the manual bootstrap approach is necessary to target parts of the DOM or "partial view" with a specific module.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
         angular.module('myApp', []);
         angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
       });
```

...but I am nervous about what I am losing according to the disclaimer

> angular.bootstrap will not create modules on the fly. You must create
>   any custom modules before you pass them as a parameter.

...and I am guessing you can't apply multiple modules to the same DOM element? Correct?

If multiple modules cannot be assigned to the same root DOM element, then what is the recommended approach?

I think inter-family/intra-family communication can be handled by a pub/sub model.

But is each widget a module?  If so then, would multiple instances of the same widget need a different module name--dynamically generated (e.g., thing1, thing2)?

Each widget can't be a controller because that would mean that intermingled families would have to have the same module.

**EDIT 1: (Example)**
A given page has a list widget and a detail widget relying on xhr-data. They are dependent on each other but can be  anywhere on the page.  Clicking an item in the list changes the detail.  Two other widgets are on the page. One has multiple selectors that influence the amount of xhr-data displayed in the other. Finally, a last standalone widget which is a self-contained accordion.  The widgets can be placed in such way that there is no single HTML node that encapsulates each family distinctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding modules.  Modules are injected into other modules, so you can mix and match however you want.  The view (partial or full page) will relate to a controller.  The controller can have access to any functions from the modules that have been injected into the module where the controller resides.

With your widgets, you'd most likely want to organize your widget families into separate modules and then inject one or more of those modules into the modules where your controllers that relate to the views live.  This allows you to mix and match based on the specific needs of the view.  The individual widgets can be a mix of functions, services, directives and filters within the widget family module.

If you have situations where widgets in different families need to use the same service (e.g. - a common API), then put the service in a separate module that's injected into the widget family modules that need it, or any other modules that need it.

I hope this sends you in a better direction.  Modules and dependency injection are awesome, because you can mix and match in so many different ways.

If you give some specific examples of widgets, widget families, common services, and how you envision them on various pages, then I could offer you some specific ideas on how to organize your code.

Comment: Thanks! So modules are not tied to a DOM element even though you have to specify a DOM element when you bootstrap the module? This means you boostrap multiple modules to the "document" and you can assign the same named controller to multiple widgets. Alternatively, bootstrap a moduleA+controller[1-n] combo to one or more DOM elements (widgets) which may or may not use the controllers in moduleA. I will add an example to the question.

Comment: You should go through the phonecat tutorial on the Angular site.  It'll help you understand some of the basics.  Modules are not tied to DOM elements.  Also you wouldn't assign controllers to widget, you'd inject the widget family modules into the modules containing the controllers which related to the views where they are needed. Allow Angular to handle the bootstrapping via the ng-app.  From the app, the modules will be inserted as needed based on Dependency Injections you define adn the controllers used in the views/page.

Comment: I look again at the phonecat example. I have watched hours of screencasts and examples and built prototypes, but it seems like I am not viewing the world the way AngularJS does or I am not explaining myself well enough. If I put ng-app="myApp" on the body tag and then call var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []), angular creates a *single* "module" and *replaces* any modules previously called "myApp".  Given <div ng-controller="MyController">, the controller will only influence what is in that div. Developers adding controllers to "myApp" will step on each other. Hmm...

Comment: Inject any modules you need into your app level module. If on the page you need a-widgets and b-widgets, you would inject these into the top level module, along with any other built in Angular modules.  Here's an example of my top level module: angular.module('WorkMgmt', ['ngSanitize', 'leModels', 'leFilters', 'leDirectives']). Everything within the [ ] is an injected module.  Any fn within these injected modules is available.  If you have common functions needed across controllers, use services. If needed across modules, use a separate module with services and inject that module.

Comment: I think a nuance I missed is that the ngApp is a *directive* that designates the root DOM element of an application and auto-bootstraps it.  Angular seems to only auto-bootstrap one App per page, but with `angular.bootstrap` you can handle it manually. However, you probably don't want to bootstrap two apps to the same DOM hierarchy. Any module can be the App if it is bootstrapped to a DOM element. The $rootScope is not shared between Apps. Here is a jsBin that experiments with this. http://jsbin.com/ISopATA/11/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: The Angular way is to have just one app per page and one or more controllers per page.  If you're trying to setup multiple apps per page, then you're probably not understanding something about Angular, or perhaps I'm not understanding what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: You definitely helped me understand the distinction between modules in general and *the* module that is the "Application".  It does seem like the AngularJS way is to have one app per page, but they didn't enforce that in the API for some reason. I merely wanted to know if conditionally present widgets would all have to interact with that one "myApp" module or if they could bring their own app with them. It seems weird the library didn't just create a default name by convention like "angularApp". Thanks again.

Comment: One reason you don't want to have more than one app per page is because you can't have an app inside of another app.  If you chose the approach to have multiple apps per page, then inevitably you'd run into a problem where you wanted to put one inside another for some reason, but you wouldn't be able to.  I suggest you stick with one app per page and follow the Angular style.